# Unable to compile software package with CMake Errors

Tags: c, cmake

I'm trying to compile an engineering software tool called FlameMaster using cmake, and I'm getting an error of the following:

```
[  1%] [FLEX][FlameManScanner] Building scanner with flex 2.5.35
[  2%] Built target Alligator
[  3%] Built target configure_source_sripts
gmake[2]: *** [src/FlameMan/lexer.yy.C] Error 141
gmake[2]: *** Deleting file `src/FlameMan/lexer.yy.C'
gmake[1]: *** [src/FlameMan/CMakeFiles/FMObjects.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 10%] Built target ArrayMan
gmake: *** [all] Error 2
```

Prior to this, I modified the CMakeLists.txt to point to my c++ compiler and Mac OS X sdk location:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/c++")
set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk")
```

and ran (from directory "Build" alongside "Repository"):

```
rm -rf *
cmake ../Repository/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

which doesn't seem to throw any errors. The error above comes when I run:
`make --build . --parallel --target install --config Release`

Any ideas on where to start with this error code?

Edit: based on some comments, I adjusted the cmakelists and used the build commands as suggested, and removed —parallel. The error is still occurring identical, even after rm -rf * and remaking ../repository as outlined

Comment: Remove `--parallel` option and show the **real** error message. Currently, `[src/FlameMan/lexer.yy.C] Error 141` is not very useful message.

Comment: It could also be helpful to do a verbose build to see exactly what commands are being executed.

Comment: Cmake normally detects compilers and SDKs just fine. No need to modify `CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible that your build is being affected by the `--parallel` option, so I'd suggest removing that and trying again. Also, I don't know if it was a typo in your post but the command to build the project should be `cmake` not `make`.

Just as a word of CMake advice, typically speaking you should never have to modify another project's CMakeLists.txt directly in order to build, that file should only be touched by the people who originally wrote the code. If you need to override the values of variables, you can do so from the command line (the same way you're already setting `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`)

i.e. from the build directory, you can run this and it will have the same effect as the edits you made to the file

```sh
cmake ../Repository/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/usr/bin/c++" -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk"
```

However, as mentioned by [@Kuba] in a comment, CMake usually does a pretty good job automatically detecting compiler and SDK locations, so unless you've heavily customized your system it probably isn't necessary to set those variables.

And one final `cmake` tip: if you successfully build the 'install' target it will install all the files into the default location for whatever system you're on: (`/usr/local` for UNIX and `C:\Program Files\` for Windows).
Unfortunately, CMake doesn't provide any easy way to 'uninstall' the program later after its been installed. So if you think you may want to remove the program in the future, it may be better to change the install location to somewhere else.
You can do this by setting the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable, just add
`-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/desired/install/location` to your `cmake` configuration command.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really helpful info. I set the CMakeLists.txt to default and got rid of the SYSROOT option, looks like maybe it wasn't needed.

You were correct that make was supposed to be cmake.

Unfortunately I get the same exact error removing --parallel